# Magento VAT Calculation

Tags: vat

We have our Magento set-up to currently charge VAT to customers in the EU (we're based in the UK) and then customers outside the EU get charged the ex-VAT price. So if the item is £20 inc VAT to a UK customer then the non-EU customer gets charges £16.67

I've got a client wants customers outside the EU to pay the same price as they would in the EU - so the item is £20 regardless of where the customer is.

We want sales in the EU to still accurately reflect the VAT but someone in the US would be charged £20 with no VAT reflected in the sales invoice.

Is there a way to do this? I'm wary about doing this and messing up our VAT calculation. I also want to keep our VAT settings the same for all our other clients on the same Magento installation (we run multiple stores under one Magento) so don't want to make a change that affects the global settings.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think You can use the Cross Border Trade
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/new-features-ce19-ee114#ee114-11400-cross
Which allows single end-user pricing by varying the amount of tax charged.